# secure Microphone Blocker for Apple devices (macOS and iOS)

Tags: privacy, hardware, apple, audio

Quote from [Hardware for Protecting Privacy and Security](https://github.com/Lissy93/personal-security-checklist/blob/master/6_Privacy_and-Security_Gadgets.md)

> **Microphone Blocker**
> A microphone blocker is a device that prohibits audio hacking, in the form of a hardware accessory for a smartphones,
> laptops etc. It functions as a dummy mic jack, so the device thinks it
> has a microphone plugged in, and hence disables the internal one

I decided after this recommendation also to block my microphone.

With a DDG search I found guide to disable the microphone with settings menu. But I trust Hardware solutions more and found [mic-lock](https://mic-lock.com/):

Questions

- How to securely disable microphone for macOS and iOS based devices without opening the device (destroy a chip)?
- Can you recommend the product Mic-Lock? The only product I found with DDG. They use aggressive marketing slogans.

Edit, after rereading the original source:

> **Note: This section is intended just to be a bit of fun, it is entirely
> possible to stay secure and anonymous, without having to build or buy
> anything.** Now that more devices have been added, it's not been
> possible to test everything here, so these products should not be
> taken as recommendations, just interesting ideas, and a bit of fun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dummy, i.e. unconnected, microphone plug was a commonly recommended security method many years ago. It worked by mechanically breaking the circuit to the internal microphone in order to connect to the non-existent external microphone.

**Those days are long past**, despite this now misguided *security* recommendation.

Nearly all modern devices use software controlled ports and connections. **Mechanical disconnects no longer work**. In fact, plugging in a working external device does not preclude the internal device from being activated simultaneously.

Comment: Any suggestions for what might work these days?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily build yourself a "mic lock" by getting the cheapest *wired microphone* solution that will work for your hardware (for example a Bluetooth dongle with a microphone that goes in. The cheaper the better, since cheaper means it won't have things like multiple microphones or Noise Cancellation microphones or things like that.

Also, cheapo gadgets are almost guaranteed to have a bulky electret microphone capsule, easy to get at, easy to sabotage:

[image]

Once you have the gadget, open it, expose the microphone capsule and unsolder the terminals or cut its wires with a cutter blade.

At worst, you will wreck the external gadget. The Apple device will stay secure at the other end of a radio connection.